# How to change the Date format of a date filed in snowflake?

Tags: format, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i am looking to change in snowflake the values of a date field which has for example this format: 2/10/17, 11/1/17, 12/18/19 to this format: 20010408, 20121226, 20010304.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I will assume that your date field is a string, since neither of those date formats are actually how Snowflake stores a date.  But to convert, you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE('2/10/17','MM/DD/YY),'YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: What if my date is '02/10/41' and I want my result to be 02-10-1941 instead of 02-10-2041?

Comment: You'd need to use the `TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START` setting for your session to inform Snowflake of how you want to handle these dates:  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#label-two-digit-century-start

Answer (score 0):

You can use TO_DATE and TO_VARCHAR to convert your format:

```
select to_varchar( to_date(v, 'MM/DD/YY'), 'YYYYMMDD' )
FROM VALUES ( '2/10/17' ) , ('11/1/17' ), ('12/18/19 ') tmp( v );
```

I assume your date format is MM/DD/YY because of 12/18/19.

If you have empty strings to convert, you can use IFF to convert them to null values:

```
select to_varchar( to_date( IFF(v <> '', v, NULL), 'MM/DD/YY'), 'YYYYMMDD' )
FROM VALUES ( '2/10/17' ) , ('11/1/17' ), ('12/18/19 '), ('') tmp( v );
```

This will return the following:

```
+----------+
| NEW_DATE |
+----------+
| 20170210 |
| 20171101 |
| 20191218 |
| NULL     |
+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

check the below url for the date output format

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html

Answer (score 0):

I try to use the same method:

SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE((RpEntTrDt),'MM/DD/YY'),'YYYYMMDD')
from CONCUR

but i get: Can't parse '' as date with format 'MM/DD/YY'

Comment: Please add a comment instead of new post. I updated my answer to cover your second question.