# I want to load my timestamp column in Snowflake

Tags: azure, datetime, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have this type of data in my timestamp field in source files

**11-06-2021 22:59:55**

I want to load this into snowflake using ADF.
In Snowflake, the timestamp format is like this '2020-03-12 01:02:03' which is different from my source data.
Can you tell me what datatype I'll have to use in snowflake ?
Or any other solution for this issue.

EDIT:

Table ddl :

create or replace table trial1 (
name varchar(100),
t varchar(100),
t1 varchar(100)
);

Query :

INSERT INTO trial1 VALUES ('ABCD', '1000', '09-10-2021 18:20:55')

SELECT TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE(t1,'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from trial1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **snowflake**, dashes and slashes are not interchangeable in [date formats](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#date-formats).

**Slashes imply DD/MM/YYYY** format, and **dashes imply YYYY-MM-DD** format. (Example: 2021/10/09’ or ‘10-09-2021’ are not interpreted as expected).

In your query to get the result, first, replace the dash (-) with a slash (/) and then convert to date.

> When you are using To_date it accepts timestamp but results only date part.

- When you convert to_date to get timestamp it gives all zeros in place of the timestamp as shown below.

[image]

- Instead, **use to_timestamp** format to get the correct results as below.

  ```
  SELECT distinct t1, 
    to_timestamp(replace(t1,'-','/'), 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS') to_timestamp, 
    TO_VARCHAR(to_timestamp(replace(t1,'-','/'), 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') to_varchar
    from trial1
  ```

[image]

Refer to this [document](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-conversion.html#label-date-time-format-conversion) for conversion functions.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to change the format of your timestamp from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY.

This can be achieved by calling a nested TO_VARCHAR(TO_DATE()). Here you can find a description of the idea: [How to change the Date format of a date filed in snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61955807/how-to-change-the-date-format-of-a-date-filed-in-snowflake?rq=1)

Basically you convert the initial timestamp to a varchar and then you convert it back with TO_DATE and pass your desired as well as the input format. Besides the Year-/Month/Day-Part, you also have to add the Hours and Seconds-format.

TO_DATE: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html
Date and Time Formats: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#date-and-time-formats

Comment: Is there a way to convert my timestamp into the snowflake one through azure data factory transformations or in snowflake itself ?

Comment: I am not the ADF expert, but this (https://www.sqlshack.com/data-flow-transformations-in-azure-data-factory/) sounds helpful. With a Data flow and a new derived column you can add expression and try to transform the column values accordingly.

Comment: Since it's taking a very long time to do the transformations in ADF. I am loading the data as string and then will make changes in snowflake.
However, when I tried to do the conversion as you suggested above, it is giving me error. I am doing the conversion on just sample data similar to my source. I am editing my original question to give all necessary information. Please take a look

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: Can't parse '09-10-2021 18:20:55' as date with format 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss'